# Truffle deployment error with infura

Tags: contract-deployment, infura, truffle-deployment

I am stuck with an issue as the contract works fine with remix ide and local ganache provider but when I am trying to use truffle with infura apis to deploy the contract over rinkeby testnet, I keep getting error.

I have tried with different gas limit values but nothing works and error is consistent.

Error :

```
(node:9286) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas limit.
    at Object.callback (/home/vineet/store/project/block-chain/ethereum/inbox/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:333:46)
    at sendTxCallback (/home/vineet/store/project/block-chain/ethereum/inbox/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:486:29)
    at /home/vineet/store/project/block-chain/ethereum/inbox/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:147:9
    at /home/vineet/store/project/block-chain/ethereum/inbox/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:152:9
    at /home/vineet/store/project/block-chain/ethereum/inbox/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/node_modules/async/internal/once.js:12:16
    at replenish (/home/vineet/store/project/block-chain/ethereum/inbox/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/node_modules/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:61:25)
    at /home/vineet/store/project/block-chain/ethereum/inbox/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/node_modules/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:71:9
    at eachLimit (/home/vineet/store/project/block-chain/ethereum/inbox/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/node_modules/async/eachLimit.js:43:36)
    at /home/vineet/store/project/block-chain/ethereum/inbox/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/node_modules/async/internal/doLimit.js:9:16
    at end (/home/vineet/store/project/block-chain/ethereum/inbox/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:127:5)
    at /home/vineet/store/project/block-chain/ethereum/inbox/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/provider.js:20:5
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/vineet/store/project/block-chain/ethereum/inbox/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:118:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/vineet/store/project/block-chain/ethereum/inbox/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/vineet/store/project/block-chain/ethereum/inbox/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/vineet/store/project/block-chain/ethereum/inbox/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/vineet/store/project/block-chain/ethereum/inbox/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:24)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

**truffle.js file**

> module.exports = {   networks: {
>       ropsten: {
>         host: "127.0.0.1",
>         port: 8545,
>         network_id: '*',
>         gas: 4700000,
>         gasPrice: 20000000000,
>       },   }, };

**deploy.js file contents:**

> const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider'); const
>   Web3 = require('web3'); const { interface,bytecode } =
>   require('./compile');
>
> const provider = new HDWalletProvider(   'account mnemonic',
>   'infura api link' );
>
> const web3 = new Web3(provider);
>
> const deploy = async () =>{   const accounts = await
>   web3.eth.getAccounts();
>
> console.log('Attempting to deploy from account',accounts[0]);
>
> const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
>   .deploy({ data : bytecode,arguments: ['hello!'] })    .send
>   ({gas: '2000000', from: accounts[0] });
>
> console.log('Contract deployed to ',result.options.address); };
>
> deploy();

Comment: What is your truffle.js file configuration? What is doing the failing deployment script? Did you try increasing the gas amount following the [documentation](http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration)?

Comment: I have edited the post to provide more details and tried many different values as gas amount but nothing worked.

Comment: You've tried to deploy it on Kovan or Rinkeby? Just to make sure it's not a Ropsten error (because it has attacks lots of times).

Comment: I tried to deploy it on Rinkeby.

Comment: Does your bytecode data start with '0x'? If it does not you have to prepend it before passing to deploy, ie something like this `.deploy({ data: '0x' + bytecode, .. })`. Another possibility is you are setting the gas limit at 2M when you send the contract, it might be low if your contract is complex, try increasing it.

Comment: the contract is very small , the suggestion that worked for me is prepending '0x' to the bytecode. thank you very much @Ismael....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked, after a lot of efforts i followed the advice given by @Ismail in the comment above.

> Does your bytecode data start with '0x'? If it does not you have to
>   prepend it before passing to deploy, ie something like this .deploy({
>   data: '0x' + bytecode, .. }). Another possibility is you are setting
>   the gas limit at 2M when you send the contract, it might be low if
>   your contract is complex, try increasing it.

**The bytecode didn't start with '0x' so i had to prepend '0x'!!!**

deploy.js file contents after changes :-

> const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider'); const
>   Web3 = require('web3'); const { interface,bytecode } =
>   require('./compile');
>
> const provider = new HDWalletProvider( 'account mnemonic', 'infura api
>   link' );
>
> const web3 = new Web3(provider);
>
> const deploy = async () =>{   const accounts = await
>   web3.eth.getAccounts();
>
> console.log('Attempting to deploy from account',accounts[0]);
>
> const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
>   .deploy({ data : '0x' + bytecode,arguments: ['hello!'] })    .send
>   ({gas: '5000000', from: accounts[0] });
>
> console.log('Contract deployed to ',result.options.address); };
>
> deploy();

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar hassle with it and my solution was to migrate with ethers.js. It's much stabler than web3.js and I am not having to deal with the truffle config anymore. I've even abstracted my solution in a simple library. Here is a snipet for infura deployment I've used to deploy using Private Key:

```
const etherlime = require('etherlime');

const ICOTokenContract = require('./build/contracts/ICOToken.json');

const randomAddress = '0xda8a06f1c910cab18ad187be1faa2b8606c2ec86';

const defaultConfigs = {
    gasPrice: 20000000000,
    gasLimit: 4700000
}

const deployer = new etherlime.InfuraPrivateKeyDeployer('Your Privste KEY', 'ropsten', 'Your infura API key', defaultConfigs);

const runICODeployment = async () => {
    const contractWrapper = await deployer.deploy(ICOTokenContract);
    const transferTransaction = await contractWrapper.contract.transferOwnership(randomAddress);
    const result = await contractWrapper.verboseWaitForTransaction(transferTransaction.hash, 'Transfer Ownership');
}
runICODeployment()
```